# Interpolate on log scale

Tags: plotting, interpolation, logarithmic-scale

I have data in Mathematica that comes from y-log scale

```
Data = {{5.0, 23.87548081003781},
   {6.94392523364486, 0.511639358262082},
   {8.925233644859812, 0.23397526329810545},
   {10.962616822429906, 0.16190746961888203},
   {12.906542056074766, 0.17751810380557045},
   {14.925233644859812, 0.25653445869951874}};
```

These points should be connected by straight line on log scale like this

```
ListLogPlot[Data, Joined -> True]
```

I want to find interpolated function with straight lines on log plot(just like above code), however naive result gives me:

```
LogPlot[Interpolation[Data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 5, 14}]
```

which does not have straight lines on logPlot, it has straight lines on Plot.

How can I interpolate data on log plot?

Comment: what if you use `InterpolationOrder` with `ListLogPlot` like `ListLogPlot[Data, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 3]`

Comment: Dear Sumit, thank you for the reply, this gives me a smoother plot, but I want an interpolated function which would look like ListLogPlot[Data, Joined -> True]

Comment: It'll be due to the difference between interpolating in log space or linear space. This'll get you what you want: `if = Exp@*Interpolation[{#1, Log[#2]} & @@@ Data, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1]` then `LogPlot[if[x], {x, 5, 14}]`

Comment: Quantum_Oli thank you very much!! Please post as an answer and I mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

*[Just noticed this was @Quantum_Oil's idea in a comment above. Probably why I didn't answer before.]*

Often one interpolates to avoid transcendental functions, but the OP's objective cannot be achieved with polynomial interpolation.  So I assume something like the following, which reproduces `ListLogPlot[Data, Joined -> True]`, is desired:

```
ClearAll[logIF];
logIF[x_] = 
  Exp[Interpolation[MapAt[Log, Data, {All, 2}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]];
LogPlot[logIF[x], {x, 5, 14}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]